# Is the Holy Quran for the humans only or for the Jinns and Angels too?

Tags: quran, jinn, malaikah

There is mentioned in the Holy Qur'an (72: 1-2)

> Say, [O Muhammad], "It has been revealed to me that a group of the jinn listened and said, 'Indeed, we have heard an amazing Qur'an. It guides to the right course, and we have believed in it. And we will never associate with our Lord anyone.

The incident of a group of Jinns being amazed by the recitation of the Qur'an. But does this mean that the Holy Qur'an was revealed for them too? If so how is it guaranteed that they come to know of it? And what about the Angels? Do they need the Holy Qur'an?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Verily, this (the Quran) is no less than a Reminder to (all) the 'Alamin (mankind and jinns)**. (Qur'an 81:27)

So, for sure, it is a guidance for humans, and **it is for Jinn too**.

> **And when we(Jinn) heard the guidance**, we believed in it. And whoever believes in his Lord will not fear deprivation or burden. (Qur'an 72:13)
>
> And (remember) when **We sent towards you** (Muhammad SAW) Nafran (three to ten persons) of the **jinns**, (quietly) **listening to the Quran**, when they stood in the presence thereof, they said: "**Listen in silence!**" And when it was finished, they returned to their people, as warners. (Qur'an 46:29)
>
> (It has been revealed to me that) **When the slave of Allah** (Muhammad SAW) **stood up invoking** (his Lord Allah) **in prayer to Him they** (the jinns) **just made round him a dense crowd as if sticking one over the other** (in order to listen to the Prophet's recitation) (Qur'an 72:19)
>
> If so how is it guaranteed that they come to know of it?

We don't know. It is a **matter of the unseen**. But, to guess, as the above two verses say, when someone recites Qur'an, the jinn might listen to the reciter. We're unsure because, the verse describes about an event which happened, but does not say that it will always happen that way. So, beyond our scope.

> And what about the Angels?
>
> Indeed, We have made it an Arabic Qur'an that you might understand. And indeed it is, in **the Mother of the Book with Us**, exalted and full of wisdom. (Qur'an 43:3-4)

Again these are the verses which just give a clue, but are not clear. The same Qur'an which we have might be of guidance to the angels too(i.e. they may consider the verses useful for them out of that Qur'an) or may be the rules pertaining to them are inscribed in the "Mother of The Book" which we have no knowledge of.

May the creator guide us all.

Comment: More over the entire Surah Ar-Rahman(55) addresses the readers as "Then which of the blessings of your Lord will you both(Jinn and men) deny?", indicating, the verses are clearly talking to the Jinn and men both.

Answer (score 4):

Yes,Quran is For humans and Jinns Only,and that because Allah leave us the freedom of choice, while the Angels have no this freedom ..

Allah said in Quraan :

> "سنفرغ لكم ايها الثقلان "(**Surat Ar-Raĥmān,verse 31**)
>
> "We will attend to you, O prominent beings"

and prominent mean humans and Jinns.

Comment: I have had a similar question at the back of my head for a long time. Do Jinns have different prophets?

Comment: do you want to say : if there were some jinn prophets ?

Comment: Maybe before prophet Mohammad .. The quraan and hadithes did not say anything about it.

Answer (score 0):

AOA wrwb

Jinns are a creature of Allah, we cant see them bt they r present in our world and as we have limited vision and senses than a lot of Allah's creation, we cant say anything confirmed about them

Many ppl have reported some supernatural incidents in their lives, it can be assumed that these creatures live around us bt we cant see or touch them as they are not limited to our 3-dimensional world. they are very much like humans as having a social life and free will.

It s said in Surah Jinn, they listened and accepted Islam, and islam means submitting one's will to Allah, so whoever does so, is actually a muslim

now there is a question by a member about prophets in jinns, thats of no benefit to us, so keep ur self away from distractions. still if u want read about Prophet Sulaiman AS who was given superhuman powers to rule the jinns and non human creatures and thats an evidence that yes jinns were categorized into believers and non believers. those who followed the path of Allah guided by Allah's messangers were among the succeeding ones.

About angels, they are Allah s creatures who never disobey Allah, they have no free will and they always follow Allah s command. thats y the mission of delivering the ayahs of Quran was given to an angel...as it was sure that there is no way this msg can be changed by the carrier or transporter
and yes they make dua for anyone who is praising Allah or reciting Allah s verses.

Rest Allah knows the best. AOA wrwb